# What is the Equivalent of alert() (javascript) in Yew (A framework in rust)?

Tags: rust, yew

I am not sure of what is the equivalent of `alert()`, in Yew.
Please tell me what is the equivalent of `alert()`.

Answer (score 1):

This is the DialogService - see the [doc](https://docs.rs/yew/0.17.2/yew/services/index.html). Example here [Rust - Yew: Simple example](https://gist.github.com/JosipHaboic/1811715de5461224ddeb4c9df5b79044).

> dialog - This module contains the implementation of a service to show alerts and confirm dialogs in a browser.

Comment: Hi, Do you know how the "Dialog Service"  is being used at Yew 0.20? The document you provided is outdated, thank you for your help.

Comment: I think you can use gloo-dialogs instead. https://docs.rs/gloo-dialogs/latest/gloo_dialogs/#